# combining variables in php

Tags: php, mysql, session, search, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
$get_crs_mysqli_count .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']) )?(" AND (course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%') OR (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userCategory'] . "%')  ") : '';
```

in it there a series of conditions:
What I want to achieve is the following:
add this to the query `(!empty($_SESSION['userCategory']) )`because i also need to ensure that this is not empty, however i am not sure how to add that in the query

Comment: Is it possible that sometime $_SESSION['userSearch'] will be set and $_SESSION['userCategory'] won't be?  Or vice versa?

Comment: that is correct, in fact you cant have them being set at the same time because it will either look to see wheter the user has search an item or a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that both options won't be set at the same time, there isn't a need to query like you expect them to be.  I would just update it to be

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['userSearch'])
{
    $get_crs_mysqli_count .= " AND (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') ";
}
elseif(!empty($_SESSION['userCategory'])
{
    $get_crs_mysqli_count .= " AND (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userCategory'] . "%') ";
}
```